# Solver for JumpOver game

Tags: prolog, puzzle

I'm learning Prolog and I want to make a solver for this game: https://www.learn4good.com/games/puzzle/brainteasers.htm

However, I can't make it work. My current code is the following:

```
solve(Balls):- 


solve2(Balls, [[]], C),
  write(C).

solve2([_],C,C). %Base case
solve2(Balls, CurrentPath,TotalPath):-
  %The first two positions should contain a ball, and the third shouldnt.
  member(B1,Balls),
  member(B2,Balls),
  \+ member(B3,Balls), 
  B1 is [X1,Y1],
  B2 is [X2,Y2],
  adjacents(B1,B2,B3),
  valid(B1),
  valid(B2),
  valid(B3),
  %Recursive call, storing the jump in the current path
  solve2(Balls2, [[X1,Y1,X2,Y2]|CurrentPath],TotalPath),
  %The ball list is the same except that the first two are removed, and the third one is added.
  delete(Balls,[B1,B2],BallsAux),
  Balls2 is [BallsAux|B3].

adjacents([X1,Y1],[X2,Y2],[X3,Y3]):- %Checks if 3 balls form a straight line
  nextTo(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,D),
  nextTo(X2,Y2,X3,Y3,D).

nextTo(X,Y,X,Y+1,1). %Checks if two balls are next to each other, the last parameter is the direction
nextTo(X,Y,X+1,Y+1,2).
nextTo(X,Y,X+1,Y,3).
nextTo(X,Y,X,Y-1,4).
nextTo(X,Y,X-1,Y-1,5).
nextTo(X,Y,X-1,Y,6).

valid([X,Y]):- %Checks if a ball is inside the grid
  X @>= 1,
  X @=< 5,
  Y @>= 1,
  Y @=< 5,
  X @>= Y.
```

What happens is that regardless of my input, the solver always returns that it can't be solved (except for the base case, which works). Anyone has some idea on how to make this work?

Edit: A input/output is something like this:

```
| ?- solve([[1,1],[2,1]]).

no
```

Basically, you call the function with a list of pairs (which are the balls coordinates on the map), and the program should write all the jumps you need to do in order to win the game. If the input only contains one ball, the output is the following:

```
| ?- solve([[1,1]]).      
[[]]

true ?
```

Here the list is empty because as there is only one ball to begin with, the program doesn't need any jump to win the game.

Comment: provide please a simple  example of input and desired output...

Comment: Edited the post, sorry I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this, it complains that B3 is a singleton variable.  Based on your comments, the first 3 lines of `solve`'s recursive version are meant to ensure that the list has a ball in position 1 and in position 2 but not in position 3.  But it doesn't do that:  it verifies that Balls has a member and calls it B1; it verifies that Balls has a member and calls it B2; it tries to verify that Balls doesn't have any members, which of course it does, and then fails.  This would explain why the recursive clause fails.

`length(Balls,3)` would verify that there's something in position 1 and position 2 but not position 3.

Also see the predicate `nth1` to get particular elements out of a list (or use [] and | appropriately).

So the problem is, I think, a misunderstanding of what `member` does.